# ASP.NET MVC HttpResponseMessage set status code above 505

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpresponsemessage

I want to use Http status code that is above 505 that is maximum in `System.Net.HttpStatusCode`. `HttpResponseMessage` can be initialized / set only using `HttpStatusCode` which cannot be inherited. Also other solution to define a custom Http status code would be fine.

Comment: Why do you think 505 is the maximum? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Have you tried setting Response.StatusCode to the value you want?

Comment: @Nikki9696 filter to net472, what we have, and 505 is the maximum

Comment: @Hintham what context is that ? In the context I see in code, it is again HttpStatusCode, so I can't just assign int value.